# jquery accordion content not hiding on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jQuery accordion script which works as I wanted it to.

But, ideally If you want to close the opened content, it should be on the second click.

[Like bootstrap accordion here.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples) And I am not using this because my menu is dynamic and has only one 'ID' (if you are wondering why I don't use this).

But, my script does not close the opened content as above example.

[JSfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manublueheart/3RH9g/)

Any suggestions to make this working as smooth as bootstrap accordion ?

My HTML :

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="accordionButton">monday</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />more weather</div>
    <div class="accordionButton">tuesday</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />more weather</div>
    <div class="accordionButton">wednesday</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br />more weather</div>
    <div class="accordionButton">thursday</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />more weather</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
$('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
    $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');    
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
});

//HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
$("div.accordionContent").hide();

 });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use toggle. i think it will work.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's accordion rather than build your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to expand only if hidden

```
     if(!$(this).next().is(':visible'))
    {
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }
```

Try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3RH9g/16/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the attached fiddle check this..[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/3RH9g/19/)

I changed the script as follow.

```
$('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("expanded")){
    $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    }
    else{
    $(this).addClass("expanded");
    //$('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');  
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }
});

//HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
$("div.accordionContent").hide();
```

});

Comment: Thanks, but this does not close the previous content if you click on new one. 
Kind of changes the whole functionality, not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will provide you Expand All/Collapse all functionality also.

**URL:** http://accordion-cd.blogspot.com/

Comment: But, still this would not solve closing the content on second click issue

Comment: Checkout Demo: http://accordion-cd.blogspot.com/2014/05/demo-2-collapse-selected.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the lightest version I could think of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.accordionButton').click(function(){
    $('.accordionContent').slideUp(300);
    if(!$(this).next('.accordionContent').is(':visible')) {                  
        $(this).next('.accordionContent').slideDown(300);
    }
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
$('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
    $('div.accordionContent').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');      
    $(this).next().removeClass('inactive').addClass('active').slideDown('normal');
    $('div.inactive').slideUp('normal');

}); 
//HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
$("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

here is the fiddle `jsfiddle.net/wTLLP/`

Answer (score 0):

Added data attributes to check the conditions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
        if($(this).data("slided") === true) {
            $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
            $(this).data("slided", false);
        } else {
            $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');    
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            $(this).data("slided", true);
        }
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

Demo - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SUDHARSHAN_R/9RKkC/)